# flex builder 3 compiler won't show errors or compile specific pages

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

In flexbuilder 3 for some mxml files I can purposely put in syntax errors and the compiler will seem to compile the specific page(but actually not compile it) or report any errors for that page. Is there any way that you know of to get the compiler to report the errors to me so I can get it to compile the page. I've tried rebuilding all and cleaning the project already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around this by compiling from the command line. [Here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=anttasks_1.html) is a link to the documentation for anyone interested(Look under Using the Flex Compilers)
When compiling from the command line I was able to get the compiler to actually tell me what error was occurring so I could fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're not actually using that page in your application anywhere. mxmlc only compiles classes that are referenced by the main class (directly or indirectly) by default.

Answer (score 2):

IF the component is not used; the compiler will ignore it.

If you're using a Library project; make sure that the component is added into the library.  You can do this in project settings.

If you're using a Flex Project; make sure that the component is actually used in the application somewhere.  Otherwise it is "optimized" out of the final swf and never given the compiler treatment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, the project path had a space in it. I renamed the folder to be without a space and reopened flex builder. Then the compilation errors started showing up as expected. Also you should have Project>Build automatically turned on.