# Force Flash Builder 4 to compile all source files

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, compiler-construction, flash-builder

According to the answers to [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760410/flex-builder-3-compiler-wont-show-errors-or-compile-specific-pages), the reason why I'm not seeing errors as I work in Flash Builder is that FB is "optimizing" them out because they aren't referenced at any point in the code execution.  Is there an option to force Flash Builder to compile all files regardless of whether they're used in the software?  This would make my development process a lot more intuitive.

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe the answer is no. Intellij Flex support, does solve that problem, but they do introduce far more problems of their own. You could trick FB by extending an dummy super class or interface.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to actually reference the class somewhere in code that you know actually *is* being compiled, such as the Document Class in a .fla, or your Main.as file in a pure AS3 project. It can be as simple as declaring a variable of the given type, even if no value is ever assigned to it.

```
private var complieMe:OtherwiseUnreferencedClass;
// ^ This will cause your class to be compiled.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference each class somewhere in your project.  The easiest/shortest way I've found to do this is to add an import followed by the class name in some common place, such as a script block in Main.mxml, although it really doesn't matter where:

```
import some.package.MyClass; MyClass;
```

Hope that helps.